# Restrict floats to allotted padding while parsing as string

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to print a series of floats with varying amounts of numbers to the left of the decimal place. I would like these numbers to exactly fill a padding with blank spaces, digits, and a decimal point.

Paraphrasing the data and code I have now

```
floats = [321.1234561, 21.1234561, 1.1234561, 0.123456, 0.02345, 0.0034, 0.0004567]
for number in floats:
    print('{:>8.6f}'.format(number))
```

This outputs

```
321.123456
21.123456
1.123456
0.123456
 0.02345
  0.0034
0.000457
```

I am looking for a way to print the following in a for loop assuming I don't know the amount of digits that will be to the left of the decimal place and the number of digits to the left never exceeds the padding which is 8 for this example.

```
321.1234
21.12345
1.123456
0.123456
 0.02345
  0.0034
0.000457
```

Similar questions have been asked about printing floating points with a certain width but the width they were talking about appeared to be the precision rather than the total number of character used to print the number.

Edit:
I have added a number to the end of the list for the following reason. The use of the specifier `'g'` with 7 significant figures was recommended by attdona. This prevents the padding from being exceeded for numbers greater than or equal to 1 but not for numbers less than 1 with precision greater than 6. Using `{:>8.7g}` instead gives

```
321.1234
21.12345
1.123456
0.123456
 0.02345
  0.0034
0.0004567
```

Where the only one that exceeds the padding is the newly added one.

Comment: As this is my first time asking on stackoverflow, I would very much appreciate any formatting, wording, stylistic, or other tips in order to make my question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the General format type specifier `g`:

```
'{:>8.7g}'.format(number)
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

**Update**: For small numbers this format fails to align correctly. In this case you may adopt a mixed approach, but keep in mind that very small numbers will round to zero

```
for number in floats:
    fstr = '{:>8.7g}'.format(number)
    if len(fstr) > 8:
        fstr = '{:>8.6f}'.format(number)
    print(fstr)
```

Comment: I thought this answered my question fully. I just realized it works for my example but I failed to consider every possibility with my example. When the number is less than 1, g uses the same amount of significant figures so the padding is exceeded by -exp when -4 < exp < 0 and by 4 when exp < -4. I have adjusted my example to demonstrate this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in floats:
      print('{:>8}'.format(f'{i:{8}.{8-len(str(int(i)))-1}f}'.rstrip('0')))
321.1235
21.12346
1.123456
0.123456
 0.02345
  0.0034
```